# Why am I unable to re-add data with the same name after removing it with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, users are able to add a loved one, like so:

```
  addLovedOne(event) {
    const {
      lovedOne,
    } = this.state;

    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        db.addLovedOne(user.uid, lovedOne)
          .then(() => {
            this.setState({ lovedOne: '' });
            this.refreshLovedOnes();
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
          });
      } else {
        unsubscribe();
      }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Naturally, users are able to remove loved ones, like so:

```
  removeLovedOne(event) {
    const lovedOne = event.target.id;

    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${user.uid}/lovedOnes`);
        const removeLovedOne = ref.orderByChild('lovedOne').equalTo(lovedOne);

        removeLovedOne.on('value', (snapshot) => {
          const lovedOneId = snapshot.node_.children_.root_.key;

          db.removeLovedOne(user.uid, lovedOneId, lovedOne)
            .then(() => {
              this.refreshLovedOnes();
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
            });
        });
      } else {
        unsubscribe();
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is what the queries look like:

```
export const addLovedOne = (userId, lovedOne) => (
  db.ref(`users/${userId}/lovedOnes`).push({
    lovedOne,
  })
);

export const removeLovedOne = (userId, lovedOneKey) => (
  db.ref(`users/${userId}/lovedOnes/${lovedOneKey}/lovedOne`).remove()
);
```

Here is what my schema looks like:
[image]

Any idea why I'm not able to add a loved one with the same name after removing it without refreshing the page?